# Why does photos show up as of part of the total storage that's taking up in my MacBook

Tags: icloud, photos

For some odd reason when I go and click on the Apple menu button then press about this mac, and select storage. When I look at what is taking up what amount of space in my mac. The one thing that does not show up on the categories is photos. I tried multiple things such as disabling iCloud photo library and signing out of iCloud. Even restarting the whole computer. I know I have pictures on my mac but they are simply not taking any space on my computer. Plz, help.

Comment: In the title, you ask *"why does photo show up"* and in the description you say *"the one thing that does not show up ... is photos"*. It's a bit confusing - Please edit and improve your question by telling us what exactly you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is simply because you have disabled iCloud Photos but the Photo Library is still on the Mac. The Photos library is located in `/Users/Username/Pictures`. Locate the one causing the issue and move it to trash then empty.